# Modify Function From Another Lua File/Scene (Corona SDK)

Tags: lua, sdk, coronasdk

Working on this for a couple of days now, but I just don't get it. 
I'll explain: I'm trying to access the addscore() function in my levels.lua through my level1.lua file on collision.

I want to do this so the next chapter of my game can be unlocked.
I'm using the composer template with Corona SDK.

So normally (if addscore was in level1.lua) it would look like this: object:addEventListener("collision", addscore)

But since addscore is in another lua file I can't just do it like that. 
I have tried it with: local levels = require("levels"), but this has no effect at all. I really would appreciate it if someone could help me because this is getting quite frustrating.

I hope I pointed out my question good enough, tell me if you need more information about my code to help me. Thanks!

Here is part of my code:

levels.lua:

```
local composer = require( "composer" )

local scene = composer.newScene()
local widget = require("widget")
local toast = require('plugin.toast')

Gamescore1=0
function addscore()
Gamescore1=Gamescore1+1
end

function nextchapter()
transition.dissolve(chapter2, chapter2open, 800, 1)
end
if (Gamescore1==1) then
nextchapter()
end
```

level1.lua:

```
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()
local levels = require("levels")

local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()
physics.setGravity (0, 0
```

Comment: edit your question please. code is not good in comments

Comment: Done, thanks. Sorry I'm quite new to this forum

Comment: You've saved addscore() in global scope. What's the problem accessing it from within level1.lua? Since it's global, it's available any time after 'levels.lua' was loaded with require().

Comment: Got it already, thought of it to hard, while it was actually very easy :L. Thank you.